# How to get the email id of new created email from a workflow step in custom workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am working a workflow where I need to get the email id of a new created email in the previous step of custom workflow.

Here is the screenshot of what I am trying to get http://prntscr.com/bu8yk6.

But instead I am getting empty string.
Any idea how can I get this ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the InArgument type of the parameter "SourceEmail" from "String" to "EntityReference". You can then assign the email created in the previous step to the custom workflow activity and then read the GUID.

```
[RequiredArgument]
[Input("Source Email")]
[ReferenceTarget("email")]
public InArgument<EntityReference> SourceEmail { get; set; }

var emailArgument = SourceEmail.Get<EntityReference>(codeActivityContext);
var emailId = emailArgument.Id;
```